# SilverStripe inline editing / hide field value

Tags: php, silverstripe

This question refers to the [SilverStripe-GridFieldExtensions module](https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions), specifically the *inline editing feature*. (ss 3.5)

The mod displays both the *current value* of a column as plain text **and** a *form input field* that naturally holds the current value by default.

The first one is not only *unnecesssary* but also confusing / not user-friendly for some fields like checkboxes (shows value `1` when checked).

**Example**

[image]

1. For the `Type` column it's really unnecessary to show the current value, as the dropdownfield already shows it.
2. The checkbox shows value `1` which is just strange for end users

**How can you disable the plain text value?**

Comment: I think this happens when you have GridFieldDataColumns() and GridFieldEditableColumns() added to your grid field config. Try removing GridFieldDataColumns()

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'd say post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you have `GridFieldDataColumns()` and `GridFieldEditableColumns()` added to your grid field config. Try removing `GridFieldDataColumns()`